# Sl 4, MVVM: Using Inlines in a TextBlock, how to bind to the ViewModel?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm

We format text for a TextBlock by adding a series of System.Windows.Documents.Run objects to TextBlock.Inlines.

How can we bind the formatted text in the ViewModel to display in the TextBlock?

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: In your ViewModel what syntax is used for the "formatted text"?

Comment: I'm retrofitting the VM to an existing app, so it's not defined yet in the VM.  Currently, we build a series of Run objects and add them to the TextBlock:  TextBlock.Inlines.Add(run).

Comment: If you "currently build a series of Run objects" that implies that you have some existing data which is formatted.  What form of markup are you currently using when storing this text?  HTML, RTF, SGML or something else?

Comment: It's diagnostic; we take information from deep in the model and display in a debug pane.  The information has no markup stored with it.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted creating an InlineCollection property in aViewModel, then set the binding in the xaml, but the InlineCollection in TextBlock is not bindable, since it is not a DependencyProperty. The answer [to this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/82b30e02-aac4-4564-9e3b-05d5622b9005/) shows creating your own control and making it a DependencyProperty which is an ok workaround.

VM:

```
private InlineCollection inlineCollection;

 public InlineCollection TextBlockInlineCollection {
    get
    {
        return inlineCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        inlineCollection = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TextBlockInlineCollection");
    }
}
```

xaml:
// doesn't work

You could also create the TextBlock dynamically in code using the XamlReader: 
example:

```
   string textBlock = @"<TextBlock xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' x:Name='infoBarTextBlockWithFormatting' AutomationProperties.AutomationId='infoBarTextBlockWithFormatting' Margin='9,0,0,0' TextWrapping='Wrap'>";
   textBlock = String.Concat(textBlock, e.NewValue.ToString(), "</TextBlock>");
   infoBar.infoBarRunHolder.Child = (TextBlock)XamlReader.Load(textBlock);
```