# how to appropriate a value in xaml to an nonbindable Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

how do i write following code as XAML

Assuming we have this snip of code

```
        var myValue = someMethodeReturn(); // the return will fit

        // could also be an other nonbindable property
        var myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        myTextBlock.Inlines = myValue;
```

how would you convert

```
       var myValue = someMethodeReturn();
```

and

```
myTextBlock.Inlines = myValue;
```

as **XAML ONLY**

surely the first part could look like  `???={Binding myProperty}`
and the secound part like `<TextBlock.Inlines><???/></TextBlock.Inlines>`
 but what would `???` be look like ?

the visual result should be something like this (if you execute youe solution)

```
    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" >
        <TextBlock.Inlines>
            <Run>meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr  lange run 1</Run>
            <Run Foreground="Green" FontFamily='Palatino Linotype' Typography.Variants='Superscript'>meine run2</Run>
            <Run>meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr  lange run</Run>
            <Run Foreground="LimeGreen" Background="Yellow">meine run3</Run>
            <Run>meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr  lange run</Run>
        </TextBlock.Inlines>
    </TextBlock>
```

i tested `ItemsControl` between the `TextBlock.Inlines` Tages but it returns TextBlocks as default and i wasn't able to set `Run` or `InLine` as `ItemTemplate`

i think i just need a `Control` that returns a `List<Inline>` but i doesn't know which `Control` will be able to do this

any suggestions would be appreciated

## i tryed the following thinks

**First**

```
<TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" >
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding myBinding}"/>
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

returns just "(Auflistung)" as Text

**Secound**

```
    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" >
        <TextBlock.Inlines>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myBinding}"/>
        </TextBlock.Inlines>
    </TextBlock>
```

returns a List of TextBoxes wrapped in a `ContenPresenter`

Comment: what are you actually asking you just placed the xaml??

Comment: @Dreamwalker the XAML is what the result should be looks like if you execute your solution ... and the Code above the xaml is code i want to convert in XAML only is this part => `myTextBlock.Inlines = myValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create bindable `Inlines` attached property as follows:

**Bindable.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public static class Bindable
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InlinesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Inlines", typeof(IEnumerable<Inline>), typeof(Bindable), new PropertyMetadata(OnInlinesChanged));

        private static void OnInlinesChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBlock = source as TextBlock;

            if (textBlock != null)
            {
                textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
                var inlines = e.NewValue as IEnumerable<Inline>;
                if (inlines != null)
                    textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
            }
        }

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBlock))]
        public static IEnumerable<Inline> GetInlines(this TextBlock textBlock)
        {
            return (IEnumerable<Inline>)textBlock.GetValue(InlinesProperty);
        }

        public static void SetInlines(this TextBlock textBlock, IEnumerable<Inline> inlines)
        {
            textBlock.SetValue(InlinesProperty, inlines);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        // This is against MVVM principle - to contain views (Inlines) in view model, but I don't want to complicate by creating ViewModel class for each Inline derived class.
        public IEnumerable<Inline> Inlines { get; private set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            this.Inlines = new Inline[]
            {
                new Run("meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr  lange run 1"),
                new Run("meine run2") { Foreground = Brushes.Green, Typography = { Variants = FontVariants.Superscript } },
                new Run("meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr  lange run"),
                new Run("meine run3") { Foreground = Brushes.LimeGreen, Background = Brushes.Yellow },
                new Run("meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr  lange run")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TextBlock local:Bindable.Inlines="{Binding Inlines}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: also a nice solution but like you said it's again the mvvm so i will choose adabyron solution

Comment: You could have also created VMs for Inlines with my solution and create custom IValueConverter which would convert IEnumerable<InlineModel> to IEnumerable<Inline> and assign it to {Binding Inlines}. I used Inline directly in view model because I didn't want to complicate the code, since it wasn't relevant to the question. Note that other solution works different than mine: it places ItemsControl inside TextBlock.Inlines, which will in fact be wrapped in InlineUIContainer which will be added to TextBlock.Inlines collection - won't work correctly for complex text formatting scenarios.

Comment: after snooping the result i see what you opined. Next time i shouldn't be to excited about in the first place better looking solution's an check the details. the result from your solution look's much nicer so and also fit's better my to my converter for my editingView

Comment: WiiMaxx: Look, I came back here this morning and wanted to change my solution, because during my sleep I remembered attached properties and behavior to be a nicer way of solving your problem. **So please change the accepted anwer to this one, @Stipo earned it, this way is better.** But do not use Brushes/Runs etc. in your ViewModel, that is not so nice MVVM...

Comment: i got an issue whit this solution because `<Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' />` doesn't result in a `Linebreake` in a `Textbox` do i miss something?

Comment: I am not sure what problem you have regarding line breaks.. Have you tried adding LineBreak instance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.linebreak.aspx) in your Inline collection? If you have WPF text formatting issue, I recommend you ask another question about it. @adabyron you are correct, having views inside view model is against MVVM, but I did it just to simplify the solution. Providing view models for entire hierarchy of Inline derived classes would be too much for this question, but it should be done in pure MVVM.

Comment: @Stipo i created a new [>>Question<<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362815/textblock-inlines-attached-behavior-issue-by-linebreak) for this Part because it doesn't fit to to this topic also i added further informations

Answer (score 1):

To add a string value you can use

```
myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(myValue));
```

If myValue is an array loop through and add multiple run elements

Msdn docs for Run class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx

Comment: i need a XAML only solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

My idea would have been to use an ItemsControl and set the ItemPanel to WrapPanel, then insert TextBlocks or ContentPresenters for each item. Turns out those TextBlocks will not wrap as nicely as I'd have expected:

[image]

Well, you at least have a ViewModel, so how about putting your text items through the meat grinder before committing them to your source collection? Looks right afterwards:

[image]

Now if it would only **feel** right as well ;)! Maybe you can use some of it, at least.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyRunModel> _myRuns = new ObservableCollection<MyRunModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyRunModel> MyRuns { get { return _myRuns; } set { _myRuns = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyRuns"); } }


    public ViewModel()
    {
        List<MyRunModel> runs = new List<MyRunModel>();
        runs.Add(new MyRunModel() { Text = "Meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr lange run1" });
        runs.Add(new MyRunModel() { Text = "Meine run2", Foreground = ForegroundDescription.HighlightDark });
        runs.Add(new MyRunModel() { Text = "Meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr lange run3" });
        runs.Add(new MyRunModel() { Text = "Meine run4", Foreground = ForegroundDescription.HighlightLight, Background = BackgroundDescription.Highlight });
        runs.Add(new MyRunModel() { Text = "Meine sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr sehr lange run5" });

        CommitMyRuns(runs);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Splits up every run into words (delimited by space), and adds the parts 
    /// to the collection that can be bound to the UI. Retains formatting information.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="runs"></param>
    private void CommitMyRuns(List<MyRunModel> runs)
    {
        int runCount = runs.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++)
        {
            string[] parts = runs[i].Text.Split(' ');
            int partCount = parts.Length;
            for (int j = 0; j < partCount; j++)
            {
                bool isLast = j == parts.Length - 1;
                MyRunModel run = new MyRunModel()
                {
                    Text = parts[j] + (isLast ? string.Empty : " "),  // add space that was lost in split
                    Foreground = runs[i].Foreground, // keep formatting
                    Background = runs[i].Background
                };
                MyRuns.Add(run);
            }
            MyRuns.Add(new MyRunModel() { Text = " " }); // add a space after each of the original runs (unformatted)
        }
    }

}
public class MyRunModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // do not use UI types (e.g. Brush) directly in viewmodel
    public ForegroundDescription Foreground { get; set; }
    public BackgroundDescription Background { get; set; }
}

public enum ForegroundDescription
{
    None = 0,
    HighlightDark,
    HighlightLight
}

public enum BackgroundDescription
{
    None = 0,
    Highlight
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundHighlightDarkBrush" Color="Green" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundHighlightLightBrush" Color="LimeGreen" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundHighlightBrush" Color="Yellow" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Inlines>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyRuns}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyRunModel}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="presenter" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foreground}" Value="HighlightDark">
                                <Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundHighlightDarkBrush}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foreground}" Value="HighlightLight">
                                <Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundHighlightLightBrush}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background}" Value="Highlight">
                                <Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="TextElement.Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundHighlightBrush}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </TextBlock.Inlines>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Subclassing the textbox to make the Inlines bindable might be a possibility. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5488319/385995).

Comment: hi nice solution but i need also `Typography.Variants='Superscript'` but i could get it to work as Setter `<Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="TextElement.Typography.Variants" Value="Superscript"/>` what do i miss?

Comment: ok i got it `<Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="Typography.Variants" Value="Superscript"/>` and 
`<Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="FontFamily" Value='Palatino Linotype'/>`