# TextBlock Inlines Attached Behavior Issue by LineBreak

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, attachedbehaviors

Hi is there a way to check if a Run is just a `LineBreak`?

## Some explenation first

suggesting you create some Text with some LineBreaks in a `RichTextBox` now let's further suggest after you want to save your text in a DataBase you will probably convert the `FlowDocument` as `XML` how i did now i want to show this "XML-string" in a `TextBlock` so i convert it back as FlowDocument write an GetAllLine extension and used a  Attached Behavior to bind to `TextBlock.Inlines` end here my LineBreak Issue occurs `<Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' />` doesn't result in a `LineBreak`.

## now here is what i got so far

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TextBlockAttachedIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBlockAttachedIssue"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock local:Bindable.Inlines="{Binding myInlines}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### CodeBehind

```
namespace TextBlockAttachedIssue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new VM();
        }
    }

    public class VM
    {
        private IEnumerable<Inline> _myInlines;

        public VM()
        {
            var myParagraph =
                "<Paragraph xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'> " +
                "<Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' />" +
                "<Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' />" +
                    " das ist text davor" +
                    "<Run FontFamily='Palatino Linotype'> " +
                        "line2  dsf adsgf sd fds gs fd gsfd g sdfg df h g hdgf h fg hhgfdh gfh " +
                    "</Run> " +
                "<Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' />" +
                    "und das ist text danach" +
                "</Paragraph> ";
            var para = XamlReader.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(myParagraph))) as Paragraph;
            myInlines = para.Inlines.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Inline> myInlines
        {
            get { return _myInlines; }
            private set { _myInlines = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

### Attached Behavior

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TextBlockAttachedIssue
{
    public static class Bindable
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InlinesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Inlines", typeof(IEnumerable<Inline>), typeof(Bindable), new PropertyMetadata(OnInlinesChanged));

        private static void OnInlinesChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBlock = source as TextBlock;

            if (textBlock != null)
            {
                textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
                var inlines = e.NewValue as IEnumerable<Inline>;
                if (inlines != null)
                    textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
            }
        }

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBlock))]
        public static IEnumerable<Inline> GetInlines(this TextBlock textBlock)
        {
            return (IEnumerable<Inline>)textBlock.GetValue(InlinesProperty);
        }

        public static void SetInlines(this TextBlock textBlock, IEnumerable<Inline> inlines)
        {
            textBlock.SetValue(InlinesProperty, inlines);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx) ever represents a line break. To represent a line break, different kind of [Inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.aspx) is used - [LineBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.linebreak.aspx).

Your text doesn't have any line breaks when viewed in [FlowDocumentReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx):

```
<FlowDocumentReader>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>
            <Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' />
            <Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' /> das ist text davor
            <Run FontFamily='Palatino Linotype'> 
                line2  dsf adsgf sd fds gs fd gsfd g sdfg df h g hdgf h fg hhgfdh gfh 
            </Run> 
            <Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' />
            und das ist text danach
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

[Paragraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.aspx), on the other hand is a [Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.aspx) element which breaks to a new line. Perhaps Paragraph is causing your issue.

Why don't you use [FlowDocumentReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx) to show FlowDocument text, instead of TextBlock?
With [FlowDocumentReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx) you would have full support for FlowDocument, including Paragraphs and all other [TextElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.aspx)-derived items.

Comment: because ähh i doesn't know a `FlowDocumentReader` exist i will check it out but i'm sure it i got the answer i need :o). **But** if my string really doesn't contains any `LineBreak` in the `FlowDocumentReader` why the does `XamlWriter.Save()` convert my _handed Linbreaks_ in my `RichTextBox` as `<Run xml:lang='de-de' xml:space='preserve' />`

Comment: in the end use `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`